# Msbuild stuck building VS2012 database project

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, sql-server-data-tools

We recently upgraded from VS2010 to the VS2012 sqlproj;  building/publishing from VS2012 only takes a minute or two and fast.

However trying to do a build in MSBuild in (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319) is taking longer than 4 hours!! cant seem to figure out why. using the below ms-build command

MSBuild /t:Build /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 /p:TargetDatabaseName="WirelineDb";TargetConnectionString="Data Source=(local);Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" /p:PublishToDatabase="False" /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="Default.publish.xml" "C:\TFS01\Blah Database.sqlproj"

stuck here for hours...
[image]

Why does it take this long with MSBuild? Also what does VS2012 use to build and publish the database, is it using MSbuild behind the scenes? or SqlPackage.exe?

Comment: What happens if you try a shorter build line like:  "msbuild .\MyDBProject\MyDBProject.sqlproj /t:build /p:Configuration="Local"  "? We do a really basic build just to generate the dacpac file and then use SQLPackage to publish it.

Comment: What happens when you add /v:diag ?

Comment: Tried the shorter build line still the same; did it with /v:diag it spat out a 1MB diagnosis file;  

It essentially takes two hours between these lines in the diagnostics file

Loading project files... (TaskId:12)
Building the project model and resolving object interdependencies... (TaskId:12)
Validating the project model... (TaskId:12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized this was happening because we were still running the old VS2010 Database Project type that was simply migrated to VS2012.  From VS2012 its a SSDT SQL Project.

Since there was no migration between VSDBP to SSDT, we had to re-create the database projects manually – i.e. we deployed latest schema into SQL Server, and then import into new SSDT project.

With the new SSDT project MSBuild only takes around 10 minutes to completely build and deploy.

Further reading about SSDT:
http://blog.navantis.com/ssdt-vs-data-dude-part-1/